# Como limitar texto em colunas com CSS?

Tags: css

Estou pegando do banco de dados um texto:

```
<p> texto um pouco curto </p>
```

E exibindo usando *columns* do css em 3 partes, porém gostaria de saber se e possível bloquear o texto fazendo com que só crie outra coluna após o `</p>`.

```
#textocolunas {
    font-size: 12pt;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
       -moz-column-count: 3;
            column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
       -moz-column-gap: 5px;
            column-gap: 5px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
       -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
            column-rule: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
```

Segue um fiddle EDITADO de como está:

[atualizado o jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/garbo78q/1/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não da pra entender sua pergunta amigo

Comment: Você poderia reformular sua pergunta? Está um pouco incompreensível.

Comment: Ainda continua confusa.

Comment: os textos serao acrecentados aleatoriamente, nao é o mesmo sempre nesse caso so resolveria esse problema

Comment: Ele está determinando a altura automaticamente para criar as 3 colunas que você pediu. Se você der uma altura fixa para o elemento, o conteúdo só quebra de coluna ao ultrapassar essa altura.

Comment: alterei e nada. continua ultrapassando

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente isto ainda não é possível. E por mais incrível que parece, a impressão de colunas só funciona no IE. No firefox imprime as colunas, mas ainda tem alguns erros. E no Chrome, não imprime as colunas.

Acesse o site da [w3c](http://goo.gl/63Jb7u) ou a [Comunidade de Desenvolvedores da Mozilla](https://goo.gl/RuCjLP).